# If $f$ is a continuous function and $\phi$ is a smooth function with compact support such that $\int\phi\,dx=1$, is $f*\phi$ Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation, smooth-functions

Let us take a continuous function $f$. Let $\phi$ be a smooth function with a compact support, such that $\int \phi(x)\,dx=1$. We consider the following convolution

$(f*\phi)(x)=\int f(x-y)\phi(y)\,dy$.
Is such a function Lipschitz continuous?

I know this function is smooth, okay. But how do I know its first derivative is bounded? I have only information about $\phi$ itself and I know it has a compact support, hence it is bounded. I suppose that it means that its derivative also is bounded in this way but can you help me? Or maybe it can be shown strictly from definition?

Answer (score 4):

The derivative of $\phi$ is also compactly supported and continuous by the smoothness of $\phi$, hence it is bounded. However, this does not mean that $f *\phi$ is Lipschitz, but, as the first sentence suggests, this will depend on $f$, not on $\phi$.

If $f(x)=x^2$, $\phi$ compactly supported on $[0,1]$ and positive, thus, for $x \ge1$ :

$$f * \phi(x) = \int_{0}^{1} (x-y)^2 \phi(y) dy \ge \int_{0}^{1} (x-1)^2 \phi(y) dy.$$

Thus, since $\int_0^1 \phi(y) dy = 1$ :

$$f * \phi(x) \ge (x-1)^2$$

and $f*\phi$ cannot be Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

However, $f * \phi$ is locally Lipschitz as $(f*\phi)'=f* \phi'$ and this derivative is bounded on any compact set by continuity of $f$ and boundedness of $\phi'$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I need only locally Lipschitz fact. However, I think that I do not understand it properly: why derivative is bounded only on compact sets? Let C be its support. Is not true that $\sup_{\mathbb{R}}\phi'(x)=\sup_C\phi'(x)$?

Comment: As the counter-example show, you can have $\phi'$ bounded but not $(f * \phi)'$. In your context, the former is nonetheless bounded on compact sets, implying the local Lipschitz continuity. For $(f * \phi)'$ to be bounded on the whole $\mathbb{R}$, you will require something more (or at least, different) than the continuity of $f$, as hinted by the other answer. Is it better ?

Comment: No, it's just I honestly did not see why it is only locally Lipschitz, look $(f*\phi)'(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)\phi'(y)\,dy=\int_C f(x-y)\phi'(y)\,dy\le sup_C f(x)\cdot\sup_C \phi'\cdot\lambda(C)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. So, where we use the "local" fact?

Comment: The inequality is not correct. The argument of $f$ is $x-y$ in the integral, not just $y$, then the $\sup$ of $f$ have to be taken over $x-C$ (meaning $x-c, \forall c \in C$), not $C$.

Comment: Okay, but so what? Even if we take $\sup$ over $x-C$ with the $x$ fixed, do we need additional assumption? This is still closed set?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand... If $x$ is fixed, then we have boundary which is depending on that $x$, so in fact we did not show anything right?

Comment: Yes you are getting closer. If $x$ is constrained in a compact set K, then $\cup_{x \in K} x-C$ is also a compact set and you can conclude that the derivative is bounded. But this will not be true otherwise, hence you will only obtain local Lipchitz continuity unless you make additionnal hypothesis on $f$, integrability for example, as described in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I need only local Lipschitz continuity and now I see it. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following facts:
$$
D^\alpha(f \ast \phi) = f \ast D^\alpha\phi,
\qquad
\|f \ast D^\alpha\phi\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_p \|D^\alpha\phi\|_{p'}\,.
$$
Hence, if $f\in L^p$ for some $p$, you can conclude that $f\ast\phi$ has bounded derivatives.

Comment: Good complementary answer to mine